# Websocket connection failed (Node, express, http, socket.io)

Tags: node.js, express, http, websocket, socket.io

I prepared this minimum repo: https://github.com/lucasscheuvens/socket-problem.git

I have a node.js `express` server that is supposed to run under the same port as `socket.io`.

This is my server-side code:

```
(async function() {
  'use strict';
  
  // environment variables
  const PORT          = 8888
  
  // npm packages
  const express       = require('express')
  const app           = express()
  const server        = require('http').createServer(app)
  const io            = require('socket.io')(server)
  const { expressCspHeader, INLINE, SELF } = require('express-csp-header')
  
  io.attach(server)

  app.use(expressCspHeader({
    directives: {
      'default-src': [SELF],
      'script-src': [SELF, INLINE, 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com'],
      'connect-src': [SELF],
    }
  }))

  // serve static files in the 'public' directory
  app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  
  // socket.io functions
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Somebody connected via socket.io")
  })
  
  // start listening
  server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT} (HTTP + SOCKET.IO) ...`)
  }) 
  
})()
```

This is my client-side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-MgkNs0gNdrnOM7k+0L+wgiRc5aLgl74sJQKbIWegVIMvVGPc1+gc1L2oK9Wf/D9pq58eqIJAxOonYPVE5UwUFA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    let socket = io(window.location.host)

    socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
      console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`)
    })

    socket.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('Connected to socket.io server')
    }) 

    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, I get this error message:

[image]

Long-polling works but I can't figure out why websockets won't.
In the Network tab, it says that the websocket connection has "Finished":

[image: websocket connection finished]

What causes this error? It seems like a pretty standard issue to me.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I got the answer somewhere else. For completeness: It's because I attach the server twice.
````

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer somewhere else.
For completeness: It's because I attached the server twice.

```
...
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
...
io.attach(server)
...
```

Complete working server script:

```
(async function() {
  'use strict';
  
  // environment variables
  const PORT          = 8888
  
  // npm packages
  const express                  = require('express')
  const { createServer }         = require('http')
  const { Server: SocketServer } = require('socket.io')
  const { expressCspHeader, INLINE, SELF } = require('express-csp-header')

  const app = express()
  const httpServer = createServer(app)
  const io = new SocketServer(httpServer, { /* options */ })

  app.use(expressCspHeader({
    directives: {
      'default-src': [SELF],
      'script-src': [SELF, INLINE, 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com'],
      'connect-src': [SELF],
    }
  }))

  // serve static files in the 'public' directory
  app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  
  // socket.io functions
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("Somebody connected via socket.io")
  })
  
  // start listening
  httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT} (HTTP + SOCKET.IO) ...`)
  }) 
  
})()
```